# Automate Byobu window creation

Tags: automation, ubuntu-14.04, tmux, byobu

I use *Byobu* on a *Vagrant* dev machine to run multiple things in one screen and to be able to suspend/restore the machine and continue where I left off the other day.

There are times when I have to recreate the machine and setting up 8+ Byobu windows with changing their names, changing to particular directories in each; not to mention running commands in them after setup.

Is there a way one could create a config file or throw in a bunch of commands that does the initial setup so I do not have to spend 5 minutes with that?

There is a currently non working example on [Commandlinefu](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/11732/start-byobu-tmux-with-pre-defined-windows), so I believe it could be done. Anyone have some up to date info how can this be achieved?

```
byobu version 5.74 (and possibly 5.60 too)
tmux 1.8
```

Comment: I am sorry to ask but why is a system administration question like this is not fitting the scope of this site? Could you elaborate on that, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using tmux, you can write a setup script using shell, like this:

```
byobu-tmux new-session -d vim
byobu-tmux new-window bc
byobu-tmux new-window bash
byobu-tmux new-window sh
```

The new session will be run in the background. If you want to attach to the new session right after it was created, add

```
byobu-tmux attach
```

in the end. You can even add these commands to your `.profile`

If you use byoubu with screen, you can describe the desired commands in an alternative configuration file:

```
screen bc
screen bash
screen sh
```

Comment: It seemed ok, but then it is still a plain tmux session and I cannot use Byobu keys in it - I prefer the F* keys. Any idea how to really transform it into a "native" Byobu session? I have created a gist to show my version: https://gist.github.com/cda46cee51acc590b8da.git

Comment: Have you tried to replace `tmux` with `byobu-tmux` in the startup script?

Comment: Do you mean when I am creating the tmux windows I should use the byobu-tmux command instead? I will try and get back to you. very soon.

Comment: Yes that prefixed "byobu-tmux" version is working the true way. Thanks again! :)